# Issue trying to install docker on WSL2

Tags: linux, windows, docker, wsl-2

I'm getting the fallowing error message when I try to run `sudo dockerd`

```bash
 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout". Reconnecting...  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Any thing that I can check to fix it? PS: I have no admin user on windows
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update the packages on the system
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade
The problem is that either the current kernel does not support creating tables (unlikely) or iptables